# In org-mode, how to include archived headings in the agenda text search

Tags: org-mode

How do I include items that have the ARCHIVE tag in the org agenda search `C-c a s`?

I know archive files are included in this search by 
`(setq org-agenda-text-search-extra-files (quote (agenda-archives)))` but I want to search archived entries within my agenda files, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can either set `org-agenda-skip-archived-trees` to `nil` or use `v` in the agenda to toggle the display of archived entries.  From the `org-agenda-skip-archived-trees` manual:

> Non-nil means the agenda will skip any items located in archived trees.
>   An archived tree is a tree marked with the tag ARCHIVE.  The use of this
>   variable is no longer recommended, you should leave it at the value t.
>   Instead, use the key ‘v’ to cycle the archives-mode in the agenda.

Comment: As I do not want my agendas to always consider archived trees, the `v` command is a good work-around to use in the text-search only. But ideally I would like this to be the default behaviour of my agenda-text-search.